# Continuous audio stream in NodeJS using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, audiostreamer

I was wondering if there is a way to have socket.io and Nodejs work as a continuous streamer for Audio like [Icecast](http://icecast.org).

> For example, one user can enter the site and hear the stream. After 10
>   seconds, another user can connect and will hear the same song but 10
>   seconds later. The stream will not depend on users connecting and will
>   run on the server and output the *.mp3 file to the client.

The closest step I've got to this is by Using the stream to transfer audio files by following the steps in here https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream/issues/73

This will detect the users who are connected but will reload the song instead of having it run in the background. Any help would be appreciated.

Best.

Comment: any news? did you get a luck with it?

Comment: Unfortunately the deadline for the project came and I had to go with Icecast. I connected it with node-icy to grab metadata info from node. Other than that there was not much documentation I could find. If you are interested in setting up your own icecast server: https://github.com/rmfranciacastillo/Sleepnet/blob/master/Install.script